# select rows with certain values of a column in pandas data frames

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe df  as follows:

```
   food      price   amount
0  apple      2.0     3
1  grape      3.0     20
2  orange     1.9     3.0
3  pork       3.0     0.5
4  lattice    1.0     1.0
5  pear       3.0     2
6  zucchini   2.5     1
7  pumpkin    2.0     0.5
8  grape      3.0     30
```

and I have the following np.array:

```
fruit = np.array([apple, pear, orange, grape])
```

I want to extract rows in the dataframes only when the name of the food is in the fruit array. So far, I have the following code which gives what I want:

```
df[df['food'].apply(lambda x: x in fruit)]
```

I am wondering if there are any other methods to do the similar thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern pandas, you can use the [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method of DataFrames:

```
>>> fruit = np.array(["apple", "pear", "orange", "grape"])
>>> df.query("food in @fruit")
     food  price  amount
0   apple    2.0       3
1   grape    3.0      20
2  orange    1.9       3
5    pear    3.0       2
8   grape    3.0      30
```

where the `@` means "the following name refers to a variable in the environment, not a column of the frame".

Comment: do you know the difference in performance? maybe query is faster? Thank you!

Comment: It varies; always a good idea to use `timeit` yourself to find out, if it's really a bottleneck.  For longer frames it'll be much faster than `apply`, but for smaller ones you won't be able to amortize the startup cost and soit might be a little slower.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df[df['food'].isin(['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'grape'])
```